# Link Console with source code in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, java-me

I have a J2Me project, that throws exceptions, in other projects (J2Se projects) I'm used to press on the exception link in the console in Eclipse, and it would take me straight to the source line, for some reason, in the J2Me project this does not happen.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Adam.

Comment: Did you fix this? I am having a similar problem [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116142/in-eclipse-console-can-i-click-on-stack-trace-and-it-should-take-me-to-java-inste](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116142/in-eclipse-console-can-i-click-on-stack-trace-and-it-should-take-me-to-java-inste)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-installing Eclipse, and creating the project from scratch did the trick, I have no clue as for why.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the stack trace to a Java Stack Trace console. In the Console, switch to a new Java Stack Trace console, paste the stack trace and it will be immediately clickable.