# In eclipse console can I click on Stack trace and it should take me to java instead of .class file?

Tags: eclipse, console, stack-trace

My config is like this

```
Java Project1: IADTPrj
J2ee Project2: TestJ2EE references IADTPrj
```

Classpath entry `<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/IDCT/bin"/>`

I have in logger get some outputs like `(SomeClass.java:30)` which I want to click to and go to its java file line no. 30. But eclipse is taking me to its .class file. To make matters worse i have a java decompiler installed which takes me to a ***look alike java code*** of **SomeClass.class** but again to the wrong line number.(line numbers are not preserved after decompiling. But it says which original java line number corresponds to current decompiled class!)

Now is this possible to define the search path for finding the hyperlinks, so that I can specify to search for java files first in the related project and then class files. So that I can edit SomeClass.java directly and re-deploy.

Comment: Your Classpath points to a library called /IDCT/bin. How is that related to either of Project1 or Project2?

Comment: @Erick, I really forgot about the folders structure, I apologize that the question itself is not clear. But things have changed since then in JDeclipse (java decompiler). It now aligns decompiled code to correct line numbers. This makes easier to debug and step through decompiled classes. By the way eclipse still sometimes does not find the java sources and debugger points to decompiled classes even if the actual sources are present in different project in the same workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you did not attach any source (jar or folder) to that class.

There are many ways to attach a source jar or folder to a jar; an easy one is to right click on the jar in the package explorer and select properties.

If you have jadclipse, then if configured correctly, the real source code should take precedence over the decompiled code.  Please be aware however, that if you change the configuration and test the same class, you will think that your configuration will not be taken into account because the decompiled source will still show up.  I don't know of any other fix than restart eclipse (or test another class).

Comment: Thanks for replying. Adding source to a class sounds good, I saw the option will test it on monday. I added source to a class file before thats when eclipse default class viewer opens a class file you get a button to add source. But it does not help as the source opens as Someclass.class you can actually see java code but not edit it, much like decompiled source. I want eclipse to fetch my original java file from a different project in the same workspace. Hope adding the source folder works now. By the way I am using JD decompiler.They have a JD-GUI standalone version

Comment: I lke JD, I did not know you could add JD to jadclipse.  Will try it. Tx

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the stack trace to a Java Stack Trace console. In the Console, switch to a new Java Stack Trace console, paste the stack trace and it will be immediately clickable.